# Directly draw on window rather than child window?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

Context: a native C++ desktop application that runs on Windows. The GUI uses plain old GDI and standard controls. The application itself is not GUI-rich but all the standard controls I use (static, button, edit and list **as a base**) are either owner-drawn, custom-drawn, or a mix of [both](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048(v=vs.80).aspx).

My question is about some parts of the GUI I draw **directly** onto the dialog/window. Each one of these parts is clearly delimited by a rectangle, which is kept as a property for fast access, and these parts get painted only when their respective rectangle overlaps the one that comes from the [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) and similar messages. Mostly to draw text and icons (transparent background). These parts don't require any end-user interaction but they display valuable information (think status bar or any other GUI element that reacts to a state change).

The result is smooth and flicker-free thanks to the use of some tricks gathered here and there.

**Q:** Still, out of curiosity, I wonder in such a case (i.e.: non rich application) **what would be the benefits** of creating a child window for each one of these "parts" instead of just sticking to the current all-in-one drawing technique? Is there any reason why I would have to think about creating children windows?

From where I stand, I see only cons of creating children windows since it would mean more resources (children windows plus their context), plus having to deal with their procedure, which means more code to write-then-maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question a few month later...

The way the described application works is just fine as long as the amount of code to deal with those *fake* control rectangles (content and drawing) does not bloat parent window's code. Also, this *technique* spares the application from the creation of any resource associated to additional (child) windows, which cannot be a bad thing.

That being said, in the case of a [layered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) parent window that is updated only with [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx), it can be preferable (more speed-optimized) to create child controls, especially if we need to update their content quite often.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of using child windows is simplification and code reuse. Microsoft has implemented many standard controls, and others are available from different sources, all of which are implemented as independent windows. A window will get messages directed at it so that the parent does not have to include logic to determine which function needs to respond to a particular message.